# How to simulate onDoubleTap in flutter test

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, gesturedetector, single-vs-double-tap

I'm trying to write a flutter test and simulate a double tab. But I cannot manage to find a way.

Here is what I have done for now:

```dart
void main() {
  testWidgets('It should trigger onDoubleTap', (tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
      home: GestureDetector(
        child: const Text('button'),
        onDoubleTap: () {
          print('double tapped');
        },
      ),
    ));

    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    await tester.tap(find.text('button')); // <- Tried with tester.press too
    await tester.tap(find.text('button')); // <- Tried with tester.press too
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
  });
}
```

When I run the test, this is was I get:

```
00:03 +1: All tests passed!
```

But I don't see any `double tapped` in the console.

---

How can I trigger the double-tap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to wait `kDoubleTapMinTime` between both taps.

```dart
void main() {
  testWidgets('It should trigger onDoubleTap', (tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
      home: GestureDetector(
        child: const Text('button'),
        onDoubleTap: () {
          print('double tapped');
        },
      ),
    ));

    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    await tester.tap(find.text('button'));
    await tester.pump(kDoubleTapMinTime); // <- Add this
    await tester.tap(find.text('button'));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
  });
}
```

I get the `double tapped` in the console:

```
double tapped
00:03 +1: All tests passed!
```